# How to get List of all Stock Items with Values via Magento REST API ( MSI )

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

In Magento 1 - I used to use the SOAP API to get stock values ( example.com/inventory/all )

We are using the latest Magento with MSI ( Multi-Source Inventory ).  I need to be able to get a list of ALL stock values for every product quickly.

The closest I can get is something like  ( we have about 1500 products )
example.com/rest/default/V1/stockItems/lowStock?scopeId=0&qty=2000&pageSize=2000

takes < 1 second but that will only give me the low stock.

I need all stock values but I don't want all Product details.